# How to set public hostname

Tags: domain-name-system

I have 100/100 mbit link with static public ip configured on interface on Cisco router. On lan side I have domain controller with dns server and computers.

How can I make that computers go outside as domain.com instead of ip address / how to set hostname to domain name.

For example: when I visit serverfault.com I want that my visit is logged as domain.com not visit from xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In order to be *seen* as a DNS name instead of IP address (if the system logging your connection is doing reverse lookups)  you need a *Pointer record* `PTR` that maps your IP to a hostname (also called *reverse DNS*).

It depends on your ISP and your internet connection contract whether you are allowed to request for `PTR` record changes for your public IP, as the `PTR` records are managed by the registered owner of the IP block. You can do a lookup on [ARIN WHOIS IP Address Database](http://itools.com/tool/arin-whois-domain-search) to see the actual owner.

If your ISP allows you to request for a custom reverse name (instead of their own or blank), you also need corresponding `A` record in the DNS of your domain, i.e.

```
example.com.                8850 IN     A       93.184.216.34
34.216.184.93.in-addr.arpa. 3600 IN     PTR     example.com.
```

Having both `PTR` and `A` mapped is **probably not necessary** unless you are maintaining an own mail (SMTP) server: the only reasonable requirement for working reverse DNS is that [reverse DNS should match SMTP banner](https://mxtoolbox.com/problem/smtp/smtp-reverse-dns-mismatch) (the name that your SMTP server uses for introducing itself):

> Some receiving mail servers may use this as an indication of a
>   possible spam source in a scoring system.  Most will not reject
>   incoming mail solely on this basis.  We recommend that you contact
>   your ISP and ask them to setup a reverse record (PTR) that matches the
>   hostname of your mail server.

Even in this case a suitable workaround is to change the SMTP banner to match the reverse DNS: you always have control on your SMTP banner even when you can't control the `PTR` record.

The logs on remote server are **not good for advertisement** as only technical persons ever sees them. Conversely, having your company domain pointing at your on-premises instead of a public server and exhibiting that this is the public IP of your office **may lure some denial of service attempts**. Therefore most organizations would want to avoid having custom `PTR` records.

Comment: Thanks, now I understand. When I started thinking about that I din't know where to start, or how to ask the question. Thanks again.

Answer (score 2):

Any services that log visits will only have access to the IP address from which the request is coming from.

To map this to a domain name they will use a [reverse DNS lookup](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reverse_DNS_lookup) (PTR record) so you need to make sure you have such a record configured for the IP address that maps to your domain.com

Answer (score -1):

I think you're asking how the internet at large can use "domain.com" to find your computer rather than using your IP address.

You need to set up a DNS A record with your ISP so your public IP can be resolved to your fully qualified domain name. If you're using a home or other network where your ISP won't allow you to create a DNS record, you can look into the many different DNS providers that will allow you to set up your A Record  for free or cheaply.  sitelutions.com is one example.

Comment: No, I want to use domain name as hostname, so when visiting some services my visit is shown as domain name.

Answer (score -2):

If you mean to access your computer on your LAN from the public internet by using a domain name like PC1.xyz.com then you should use a DNS hosting provider which will allow you to map a fully qualified domain name to your static IP address. You can choose DNS hosting providers [here](https://www.keycdn.com/blog/best-free-dns-hosting-providers/).