# aws apache2 reverse dns on shared hosting server

Tags: amazon-ec2, apache2, reverse-dns

I have a server on Amazon (Apache2/ubuntu server).
I am using it to host a handful of websites. Although all the sites use gmail or other external mail providers to send and receive email I have mail setup on the server because I need the server to be able to send password forget emails and other basic emails that also would not be needing to be sent so often.

With that I also need to ensure the emails dont get blocked or go to spam folder. So I need a rDNS record setup.

My question is the server hosts like 5 different hosting accounts each with there own domain name and everyone just sets an A record to point their domain to the server. So I have no nameservers setup or any domain like that setup on the server just all the client domains.

Also I do not have access to each of the client domain names and do not want to have to use route53 could I setup the reverse dns on the ec2 server itself or on my Godaddy account where I have my domain registered?

Looking for advice thank you.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Reverse DNS Setup for an IP with multiple domains](https://serverfault.com/questions/815054/reverse-dns-setup-for-an-ip-with-multiple-domains)

Comment: Well I did see that post but it looks like that poster has a name server like ns1.domainnetwork.co.uk setup to point to the servers and then he has all the sites set to use that name server. Where my setup is different I do nOt use a nameserver I just have all the sites set an A record to get there sitre on the serve

Comment: The point is that you use your own domain name, not your customers.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this form (https://console.aws.amazon.com/support/contacts?#/rdns-limits) to request rDNS.

if your email volume is not high, another option (preferred and recommended one) would be to use SES service. If your email volume is low, you may never pay anything for SES.